# Scaling of a bar plot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, scaling

Ok so I already have my barplot all set up. This is what it looks like

[image: this is what it looks like]

and this is my code:

```
TAB2 <- prop.table(TAB, margin=2)
par(mar=c(11.5, 4.1, 0.5, 2.1))
barplot(t(TAB2), las=2, ylim = c(0,1), legend=TRUE, ylab="relative Häufigkeit")
```

the only problem I have is the scaling. I want it to look like this one that I've created with SPSS but so far I had no luck. Here is my SPSS plot:

[image: my spss plot]

Any ideas?

Comment: Without a MWE, we cannot give you a concise answer. Please add a dataset.

Comment: Might work better with prop.table(table(TAB), margin=2), but we cannot tell since you have not included information about the structure of TAB. With current arrangement you might need to multiply each of the grouped values by 1/sum(x). And then relabel your y-axis. But hard to tell.

Comment: thanks 42, yours worked